# Will upgrading Azure VM wipe out vm?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We'd like to upgrade a Azure VM we're running our SQL instance on to the larger server.  When we upgrade the VM will that wipe out everything installed on the server like SQL server?

Comment: This belongs on ServerFault. But... I'll post an answer, making the assumption that it'll get migrated along with the question.

Comment: Upgrading the Azure VM wiped out both my OS and added Data disks to all 0s.  I ended up having to re-build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VHD is stored in a blob (a page blob, to be exact). This is completely separate from the Virtual Machine resources ("compute") running the OS within the VHD.

If you upgrade, you won't have any issue with the OS disk, nor with the attached disks (up to 2 per core). You *do* run the risk of losing your temporary storage (typically on the D drive), as that's local storage and is not considered *durable*. And... when you increase your instance size, there's the chance that the current Host box doesn't have enough resources for the larger VM size, resulting in it being moved to another Host OS box (and then you will certainly lose your temporary storage, but still... no loss to OS disk).